# Make Windows 10 bootable USB in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: windows, windows-10, kde, bootable-media, kubuntu

I have been trying to make bootable USB drive to install windows 10 but nothing works.
Applications I have used till now:

1. unetbootin -  It give error while booting "automatic boot selection in 10 seconds" but it never boots. Loops on the 10 second, it seems its a known issue.
2. mkusb - it worked with windows 8.1 drive but it asked for missing driver in installation media and after it was made bootable USB drive was not detected by file explorer, so can't place driver in it. Tried with windows 10, it resulted in error while booting "operating system not found in USB drive".
3. etcher - it gives error "operating system not found in USB drive"
4. dd command line - It copies and pastes the ISO content to USB, gave same error as etcher.
5. Rufus in windows system - it gives error, "ERROR: BIOS/LEGACY BOOT OF UEFI-ONLY MEDIA" and suggest to either change the boot mode in BIOS or format drive as MBR and copy content to USB drive.
   I Tried looking for the boot option in BIOS but its not there. I have tried formatting drive as MBR partition and pasted ISO content to USB drive tried booting from USB, still same error as before "ERROR: BIOS/LEGACY BOOT OF UEFI-ONLY MEDIA"

I am using Dell Studio 1555, it was running windows 7 from beginning, updated to windows 10 through automatic update and replaced it with Kubuntu 20.04 recently.
Now I wanna go back but it seems its difficult to go back to windows once you leave.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I Tried looking for the boot option in BIOS but its not there.

It's in the Rufus user interface (i.e. in the Rufus application itself), **when you create the drive**, that you need to change those options, not in the BIOS. If you recreate the drive with Rufus you will see that, exactly as the message you saw indicates, you can select `MBR` under the *Partition scheme* field, and then `BIOS or UEFI-CSM` under the *Target system* field once you have selected your Windows ISO.

What the message tells you to do is to go back to Rufus and recreate the media after making sure you alter the *Partition scheme* and *Target system* options of Rufus as described above.

For more on this, please see the Rufus FAQ, that has a [dedicated entry on this matter](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#ERROR_BIOSLEGACY_BOOT_OF_UEFIONLY_MEDIA).

Answer (score 0):

Use WoeUSB to create a bootable disk for both BIOS and UEFI

```
add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
apt update
apt install woeusb -y
```

If it requires additional dependencies you can find them on pkgs.org or:

```
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/w/wxwidgets3.0/libwxgtk3.0-0v5_3.0.4+dfsg-8_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.2-2+b1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt install woeusb -y
```

Next you need to unmount your USB-drive and clear partition table:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=512 count=1
```

Use `woeusbgui` to start WoeUSB