# How to make a bootable flash drive with Windows 10 from Cloudready?

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, windows-installation, chromebook

I have a laptop with cloudready (latest version) installed on it.
I just bought another laptop without a operating system on it.
At the moment i don't have access to a device with windows 10 to make a bootable stick with media creation tool.

I made a bootable stick with windows 10 on the cloudready laptop (renamed .iso to .bin and with Chromebook Recovery Utility i made the flash drive) , but when i put it in other laptop a window with Install Now appear ,
after that a window with mention `A media driver your computer needs is missing`...
After that the installation stuck and providing no driver.

On cloudready laptop i have an AMD processor resulting in that Linux Beta doesn't work.

My question is there is a way to create a bootable stick with windows 10 ( on a cloudready laptop ) that runs till the end of installation ?

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1596724/make-windows-10-bootable-usb-in-kubuntu-20-04?rq=1) is one method

Comment: If you have `dd`, this is as simple as `dd if=file.iso of=/dev/sdX status=progress`. You need to format the device as NTFS.